# Turn off Eclipse formatter for selected code area?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

When I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> up the project code, its doing its job just fine, everywhere.

But its messing the CSS, specially those filter parts and adding bunch of spaces.

Also how do I specify some portion of Java code to not be formated by that command ?

Comment: Do you have a CSS inside your .java class?

Comment: nope. .css but i want the annotation or stuff like given here @formator:on and off but dont know how to implement it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code/3353765#3353765

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To prevent specific portions of Java code from being formatted, go to "Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter". Click the "Edit..." button, go to the "Off/On Tags" tab and enable the tags. Afterwards, you can simply embed those tags in Java code to disable the formatting in-between them. If you don't change the default tags, something like this will do :

```
//@formatter:off
this.
    portion.of(code
); // will not be touched by the formatter
//@formatter:on
but this will be
       reformatted.
```

IIRC, this option only exists since Eclipse 3.6.

As for css code, if you have installed Eclipse WTP, go to "Window > Preferences > Web > CSS Files > Editor" and you will find some basic formatting options there.

Comment: awesome . thanks , its aint in Galileo but its in Helios .,

Comment: Yes, that was my "only exists since Eclipse 3.6" part :). I wasn't sure, but your comment did confirm that this option wasn't in Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo).

Comment: Note this needs to be enabled in your preferences formatter settings.

Comment: Any short cut to do this for a block of code with out typing formatter:off and on?

Comment: Nice one. Is there a similar feature for organise imports. As I do not want static imports * to be removed. For eg. import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

Comment: It is not working with my Eclipse 2021-03 installation. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot configure the formatting at class level, but you can configure at the project level.
To do the configuration follow this path in eclipse

**window->preferences-> java -> code style -> formatter**

now select the **configure project specific settings** and do your changes.

Comment: Quite helpful thanks!!