# How to turn off VSCode formatting for certain sections of a file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have the following JS in vscode:

```js
let page = document.getElementById("page");

$$$$<h1 style="text-align:center">[this.courseNum] : [this.name]</h1>

let hr = document.createElement("hr");
/// more Vanilla JS code...
```

I'd like to be able to turn off the formatting for that weird JS/HTML mixture above; the line preceded by $$$$. Is there anyway to turn off formatting for a line preceded by a series of characters ([such as the @formatter: off tag that Eclipse uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115088/turn-off-eclipse-formatter-for-selected-code-area)). Or, more generally, is there a way to turn off the formatter for certain regions in a file?

Comment: I don't believe there is a general setting for this, but perhaps there is an extension with support for this.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I will look and update if I find any such extension.