# Disabling Eclipse code formatting for part of a javadoc

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, javadoc, weka, eclipse-jdt

I have a Java class for which part of the javadoc is actually generated as part of the build process: the return value of a method (a static String value) is inserted into the source file, much like `$Revision: $` tags work in some version control software.

While this behaviour may be questionable, such duplication of information is required by the framework I use (WEKA machine learning library). I would like Eclipse's code formatter not to interfere with the generated comments. I am using the Eclipse Indigo release.

I can turn the formatter on/off with special comments `//@formatter:on` and `//@formatter:off`. However, the `@formatter` tags are only functional in 'normal' comments, not in javadoc comments. Obviously, they could be easily confused for javadoc tags. This means I cannot turn off the formatter (for example, automatic line breaking) for the generated part of the javadoc comment, and leave it on for the rest, because the `@formatter` directives must be placed around the javadoc comment.

It there a workaround to toggle code formatting inside javadoc comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable formatting for the header, but I don't believe you can selectively disable formatting for nonheader javadoc comments.

Comment: Quite a long time has passed since I asked this question. Anyways, I accept this answer since it is, as a matter of fact, entierly correct.

Comment: Likewise, based on empirical testing, you cannot selectively disable formatting for non-header block comments, e.g.:
/* comment */

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1025619/1135954) explain a work-around by including the html tags.

Answer (score 13):

Been a while since this was asked/answered and helped me refine the following answer, hopefully additionally useful. I use this alternative as I wanted to run Javascript in Javadocs.

Eclipse provides the @formatter:off and @formatter:on which needs to be enabled via Windows->Preferences->java->code style->formatter:::edit button::: tab "off/on tags".
They may be used in any comments.

Around the doc stuff

```
// @formatter:off
/**
* javadoc
*/ 
// @formatter:on
```

But when you want the formatter off within the javadoc use the 
@formatter:xxx within html comments `<!-- xxxxx -->` to indicate what you
are trying to do. Use the `<code>...</code>` bloack to ensure no formatting and 
the inclusion of code as javascript.

Editted the code statements in the example as I wanted this to work on eclipse
and netbeans. I found the formatter:off work but then stopped working on a different
version of eclipse (yes I use multiple IDE versions).

```
/** 
* <br><!-- @formatter:off -->
* <code>
* <script type="text/javascript">
* // hash structure for holding variable as name and its text
* var hashText = {};
*  
* // function causes a hyper-link to be created
* function insertLink(varName, text){
*    var link22;
*  
*    hashText[varName] = text;
*  
*    link22 = '<a href="./ConsoleCapture.html#' + varName + '">' + hashText[varName] + '</a>';
*       
*    document.write(link22);
* }
* function insertLinkA(varName){
*    var link22;
*
*    link22 = '<a href="./ConsoleCapture.html#' + varName + '">' + hashText[varName] + '</a>';
*
*    document.write(link22);
* }
*      
* function setLinkPoint(varName, text){
*     hashText[varName] = text;
*      
*     document.write('<a id="' + varName + '"><U>' + hashText[varName] + '</U></a>');
* }
*      
* function setLinkPointA(varName){
*    document.write('<a id="' + varName + '"><U>' + hashText[varName] + '</U></a>');
* }
* </script>
* <code>
* <!-- @formatter:on -->
*
*
*/
```

Comment: Thanks. Only the [// @formatter:off] syntax worked for me. I'm using Eclipse STS 3.6.1.RELEASE

Comment: Somewhere between then and 2018, the autoformatter is controlled by using `autoformat:off` instead of `formatter:off` (and on), but the principle still works. My initial thought was putting in a `<span style="display: none;">` or something to stop the autoformatter instruction from showing up in the javadoc, but of course the HTML comment idea is much better, so thanks :-)

Comment: '@formatter:off' and '@formatter:on' worked out of the box in Eclipse 2019-03 for me within javadoc comments

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and changing `@formatter:off` to `FORMATTEROFF` did the trick for me.

the idea is to avoid using `@` in the on/off tag.

Now I can disable the formatter around a part of a javadoc.